# Display the sql that generated a view -Sql Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Do i need some permission to view the sql command that generated a certain view?

Because I put this option and nothing appears

Sql Developer - v 21.2.0.187

Oracle Version: 19.0.0.0.0

[image]

Comment: Well, the first question is  . . . what is that client IDE that you are using?  And what version (to 4 decimals) of oracle are you connected to?

Comment: @EdStevens Sql Developer - v 21.2.0.187, Oracle Version? 19.0.0.0.0

Comment: same question as here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70799376/sql-developer-version-21-2-view-definition-not-displaying-view-sql-dont-display/70802995#70802995

Answer (score 0):

You can select from the `ALL_VIEWS` view to see the source code of a view. The `TEXT` column contains the full source of the view. The `TEXT_VC` column displays the first 4000 characters of the source code of the view as a VARCHAR2.

I'm not 100% sure, but the tab may be using `DBA_VIEWS` which is similar to `ALL_VIEWS` but the user you are connected as may not have access to it.

Comment: You have this code?, You have this code, I tried it here, but I couldn't run it